# ScrollView not scrolling down

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-scrollview

I am building an application and the ScrollView function is not scrolling down (not working), it only views a number of buttons and the rest of the buttons are not there!

It should view the rest of the buttons when I scroll down (buttons are retrieved from a loop)! but unfortunately it doesn't work!

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

    tools:context=".viewdevices">

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/username"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:paddingTop="300dp"
         android:text="@string/username"
         android:textAlignment="center"
         android:textSize="30dp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:typeface="serif"

         />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/username"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scroll_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button

                android:id="@+id/devicename"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

can anyone figure what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the ScrollView not scrolling might be due to the height of the ScrollView and the LinearLayout inside it. The height of the ScrollView is set to "match_parent" which means it will take up the full height of the parent layout. The height of the LinearLayout inside the ScrollView is set to "wrap_content" which means it will only be as tall as its contents.

If the number of buttons inside the LinearLayout is more than what can be displayed on the screen, the ScrollView will not be able to scroll as its height is already taking up the full height of the parent layout.

To resolve this, you can change the height of the LinearLayout inside the ScrollView to "match_parent". This will make the height of the LinearLayout expand to accommodate all its contents and the ScrollView will be able to scroll.

Here's the modified code:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/scroll_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't not work, still not scrolling!